# Why echo incorrect value on this code?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Why echo incorrect value on this code ?

When you fill data into input like this

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/gee/blkvz4.jpg

it's will echo

```
111
8
333
444
8
666
777
8
999
```

Why not echo

```
111
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
```

How can i do ?

............................................................................................................................................................

This is full code

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
?>

<div>
TEST NUMBER<br>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <p>
        <label>  <input type="text" name="number[]"> Number &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;By&nbsp;<input type="text" name="price"> / <input type="text" name="time[]">    
        </label>
    </p>
<p>
        <label>  <input type="text" name="number[]"> Number &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;By&nbsp;<input type="text" name="price"> / <input type="text" name="time[]">    
        </label>
    </p>
<p>
        <label>  <input type="text" name="number[]"> Number &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;By&nbsp;<input type="text" name="price"> / <input type="text" name="time[]">     
        </label>
    </p>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
</div>
</div>



<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $number = '';
        $price = '';
        $time = '';

      for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["number"]);$i++)
        {
        $number = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number'][$i]);
        $price = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace(',', '', $_POST['price'][$i]));
        $time = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['time'][$i]);

            echo $number;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $price;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $time;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The name of this field is wrong:

```
<input type="text" name="price">
```

It should be

```
<input type="text" name="price[]">
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

`<input type="text" name="price[]">`
instead of

```
<input type="text" name="price">
```